# Dockerized Django On Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, docker

I am using:

1. Ubuntu 16.04.
2. Docker version 1.12.6.

I want to containerize my existing Django app., knowing that everything goes well in this app. => no bugs, no errors...

> My Dockerfile:

```
FROM django

ADD . /BackendServer

WORKDIR /BackendServer

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "BackendServer/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

> requirements.txt

```
djangorestframework
gunicorn
```

Now everything goes well, except the last line when executing the manage.py python, it says: "python: can't open file 'BackendServer/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

So, I execute the following command: "sudo docker run backendserver ./BackendServer/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

I got no errors and still the server is not running!!
[image: errors screen]

What shall I do so that I can access the django server !? Please help!!

Additional note:
[image: here is the execution of "ls BackendServer" in the container.]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already changed the directory into `/BackendServer`.

Use this instead:

```
CMD [ "python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Also note that `docker run` executes without a tty by default, which will suppress the output. Run with `-it` to use interactive terminal.

Comment: I used it " CMD [ "python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]",
but I got the same error "python: can't open file 'BackendServer/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: You are right, after running it with -it I got some errors I will deal wih them :D, thanks ...

Comment: Please remember to rebuild the container after you change the Dockerfile.